# Menu - Focus onmouse

Tags: menu, focus, mouseover, mouseout

I have a menu that calls the above events at the main div.

```
mouseover
function() {
$('.box-content-category').addClass('active');
$(".box-content-category").show(1);
}

mouseout
function() {
$('.box-content-category').addClass('active');
$(".box-content-category").hide(1);
}
```

The problem. When the user sets the mouse (mouseover) to below div to explore the menu the menu dissapears.

How can i set the menu to stay open on mouseover and close when the mouseout at the above divs?

Thank you
Wish you the best